# Discord.js Welcome Message dont show avatar

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have the following problem. This code works, but if a User hasn't a profile picture, it shows an error and didnt send the Embed.

The Code:

```
   client.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {   
     welcome = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./commands/welcome.json", "utf8"))
     if(!welcome[member.guild.id]) return
       if(!welcome[member.guild.id].channel) return

        const welcome1 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${member.user.username} left the server`)
        .setDescription("Please come back, it was such a good time with you :(")
        .setColor("RED")
        .setThumbnail(`${member.user.avatarURL}`)

        member.guild.channels.get(welcome[member.guild.id].channel).send(welcome1)

     })
```

The Error:

```
    (node:16164) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.thumbnail.url: Not a well formed URL.
    at C:\Users\Bendix\Desktop\MemeBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:85:15
    at C:\Users\Bendix\Desktop\MemeBot\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:16164) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:16164) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
     welcome = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./commands/welcome.json", "utf8"))
     if(!welcome[member.guild.id]) return
       if(!welcome[member.guild.id].channel) return

        const welcome1 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${member.user.username} left the server`)
        .setDescription("Please come back, it was such a good time with you :(")
        .setColor("RED")
        .setThumbnail(`${member.user.displayAvatarURL()}`)

        member.guild.channels.get(welcome[member.guild.id].channel).send(welcome1)

     })```
````

Answer (score 1):

That's because the default avatar is not stored under .avatarURL but under .defaultAvatarURL. So you'd have to do something like this:

```js
let url = member.user.AvatarURL == undefined ? member.user.defaultAvatarURL : member.user.avatarURL

const welcome1 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${member.user.username} left the server`)
        .setDescription("Please come back, it was such a good time with you :(")
        .setColor("RED")
        .setThumbnail(url)

        member.guild.channels.get(welcome[member.guild.id].channel).send(welcome1)
```

This way it uses a one-line if statement to check if the user has a custom avatar, and if not replaces it with the default one.

Comment: If I tried this, but it ever displays the default Avatar.

Comment: If it displays the default avatar URL, that means the user doesn't have a custom avatar set.

Comment: But it has a custom Avatar

Comment: So you're saying it even displays the default avatar if the user has set a custom one?

Comment: Yes, I'm useing [this](https://www.memebotdc.de/Pics/Code1.jpg) code right now and it displays [this](https://www.memebotdc.de/Pics/display.jpg). And this user has a Profile picture

Comment: Try logging member.user.AvatarURL and tell me what it returns